# Confidence interval of a random variable for an ordinary linear regression

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, regression

I have a small problem. With my limited stats background I am not sure I am getting this one right.
After fitting an ordinary linear regression model I get
$$\hat{\underline{Y}}=X\hat{\underline{\beta}}$$
Now the problem is to calculate confidence interval of not observed $Y_{\alpha}$. Is this incredible stupid to just calculate confidence interval for each $\beta_j$, say $\hat{\beta_j}\pm\epsilon_j$ and then look at $a:=\sum{\epsilon_j} x_{ij}+\hat{\sigma} z$, (z=1.96 usually) where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of an error term of a model $$\underline{Y}=X\underline{\beta}+\underline{\epsilon}, \underline{\epsilon} \sim N_n(0,\sigma^2I_n)$$
Now It seems intuitive to claim that $(\sum{\hat{\beta_j} x_{ij}}\pm a)$ is the confidence interval for $Y_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Confidence intervals are for *parameters* not for *observations*. You *observed* $Y_i$, so you know exactly its value. It makes no sense to talk about the "confidence interval" of an observation.

Comment: A side note: In mathematical typography, if you wish to stress the fact that a certain symbol denotes a vector, then **bold face** is (typically) used. This is achieved in $\LaTeX$ math by using `\mathbf`.

Comment: sorry for confusing you, but I am talking about confidence interval for not observed $Y_i$, by plugging in your X

Comment: Ah, ok. You mean a [prediction interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) then. :)

Comment: the link is somewhat helpful, but not much. I know that $Y_{\alpha}=x_1*\beta_1+x_2*\beta_2+...+x_n*\beta_n+\epsilon$, so $Y_{\alpha} \sim N(\sum{x_i*\beta_i},\sigma^2)$, I know s.e. of $\hat{\beta_i}$'s, and I know $\hat{\sigma}$. Somewhat challenging to find prediction interval for $Y_{\alpha}$ though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times1}$, and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}_n(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n)$, where $\mathcal{N}_n$ is the $n$-dimensional normal distribution, and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  The least-squares estimator of the $p\times1$ vector of coefficients is
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY \sim\mathcal{N}_p(\beta, \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}).$$
The vector of predicted values is
$$
\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}_n(X\beta,\sigma^2 H) = \mathcal{N}_n(X\beta,\sigma^2 X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T).
$$
(Reminder to "pure" mathematicians: Some matrices are not square.  The "hat matrix" $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is *not* an identity matrix unless $X$ is square, and if $X$ were square, this whole discussion would be silly.  In fact, $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $p<n$.)

The vector of residuals (not to be confused with the vector $\varepsilon$ of *errors*) is
$$
\hat{\varepsilon} = Y - \hat{Y} = (I-H)Y \sim \mathcal{N}_n(0,\sigma^2 (I-H))
$$
with $H$ as above.  That the residuals $\hat{\varepsilon}$ are actually *independent* of the predicted values $\hat{Y}$ can be seen by joint normality and uncorrelatedness:
$$
\operatorname{cov}(\hat{\varepsilon},\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{cov}((I-H)Y, HY) = (I-H)\operatorname{cov}(Y, Y)H^T = (I-H)\sigma^2 H = \sigma^2(H-H) =0.
$$
Since $I-H$ is the matrix of an orthogonal projection onto a space of dimension $n-p$, we have
$$
\frac{\|\hat{\varepsilon}\|^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-p}.
$$

Summary of the foregoing:

- $\hat{Y}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ have the normal distributions noted above.
- The sum of squares of residuals $\|\hat{\varepsilon}\|^2/\sigma^2$ has the chi-square distribution noted above.
- The sum of squares of residuals is *independent* of $\hat{Y}$ and of $\hat{\beta}$.

What is the probability distribution of one predicted value?  Take $\hat{Y}_1 = [1,0,0,0,\dots,0]\hat{Y}$ $= [1,0,0,0,\dots,0]X\hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}_1(\bullet,\bullet)$.  I'll let you fill in the two blanks.  For the expected value, multiply on the left by $[1,0,0,0,\dots,0]$; for the variance, multiply on the left by that same thing and on the right by its transpose.  notice that this is *independent* of the sum of squares of residuals.

So we get a Student's t-distribution:
$$
\frac{(\hat{Y}_1 -\mathbb{E}(\hat{Y}_1))/\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(\hat{Y}_1)}}{\sqrt{\|\hat{\varepsilon}\|^2/(n-p)}} \sim t_{n-p}.
$$
From this we get a confidence interval for the average $Y$-value given the $x$-values equal to whatever they are for the first $Y$ value, i.e. the first row of the design matrix $X$.

What do we do for a set of $x$-values other than the observed ones?  Instead of $[1,0,0,0,\ldots,0]X$, just use that row vector of unobserved $x$-values.  This gives us a confidence interval for the corresponding expected $Y$-value.

But now we want a prediction interval for the next observed $Y$-value.  We're given the yet-unobserved set of $x$-values.  The new $Y$-value is independent of all of the foregoing.
$$
Y - \hat{Y} \sim\mathcal{N}_n(0,\sigma^2+(\text{the appropriate entry from }\sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)).
$$
It's all still independent of the residual sum of squares, which has a chi-square distribution.  So we get another Student's t-distribution, and base a prediction interval on that.

The above is a hasty sketch of how you derive the prediction interval, but I haven't given the bottom line.  Lots of books will give you the bottom line without the derivation.

Comment: Reminder to "applied" mathematicians: *Even* a "pure" mathematician knows what an orthogonal projection (matrix) is. :)

Comment: Once upon a time a highly respected "pure" mathematician told me that $X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$ is obviously the identity matrix.  I've seen a few other instances that I don't remember right now.  I don't really think of myself as "pure" or "applied", but I wonder if there's a reason why Paul Halmos' book _Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces_ doesn't include singular value decompositions.

Answer (score 0):

This is brilliant! Filling in the gaps:

$$\hat{Y_1} \sim \mathcal{N}_1 (\sum\limits_{j=1}^p {X_{j1} \cdot \beta_j}, \sigma^2H_{11})$$

Unobserved, let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_p)$

$$\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x} \equiv \mathbf{x}\cdot\hat\beta \sim \mathcal{N}_1 (\mathbf{x}\cdot\beta, \sigma^2\mathbf{x}(X^TX)^{-1}\mathbf{x}^T)$$
$$\tau^2 \equiv \mathbf{x}(X^TX)^{-1}\mathbf{x}^T$$
$${\hat\sigma}^2 \equiv \|\hat\varepsilon\|^2/(n-p)$$
$$\frac{(\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x}])/\sigma\tau}{\hat\sigma/\sigma} \sim t_{n-p}$$
So $\mathbb{E}[\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x}]$ is in $$(\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x} \pm \hat\sigma\tau \cdot t_{\alpha/2})$$
For prediction interval:
$$\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x}-Y_\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(\hat\beta-\beta)-\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2(\tau^2+1))$$
(Independence of $\varepsilon$)
$$\frac{(\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x}-Y_\mathbf{x})/\sigma\sqrt{\tau^2+1}}{\hat\sigma/\sigma} \sim t_{n-p}$$
Hence the prediction interval is
$$(\hat{Y}_\mathbf{x} \pm \hat\sigma\sqrt{\tau^2+1} \cdot t_{\alpha/2})$$